# multimodule project: reuse static method between test classes from different modules

Tags: java, junit, static, classpath

I have a multimodule java maven project. I added a static method to junit class of  module A. Now I would like to reuse this static method from the juinit test of module B.

**module 1:**

```
public class AccountDAOTest {

    private static Faker faker = new Faker();

    public static Account getRandomAccount() {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.set...(faker.idNumber().valid());
        ...
        return account;
    }

    @Test
    public void getByName() {
        Account expected = getRandomAccount();
        accountDAO.persist(expected);
        assertNotEquals(expected.getId(), null);

        Account actual = accountDAO.getByName(expected.getName());
        assertNotNull(actual);
    }

    ...
}
```

**module 2 (trying to reuse the static method):**

```
public class BusinessBeanTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        Account account = AccountDAOTest.getRandomAccount();
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the *AccountDAOTest.java* is not in the class path of module 2 test either I add module dependency in the `pom.xml` of module 2 with test scope.

I can see only two solutions:

- duplicate this metod and copy it from module 1 test class to module 2 test class
- remove *getRandomAccount()* method from test class and add it to a common module as a real code.

None of the above two solitions looks good.

Any idea hot to do this on a correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating jar only with tests and then include it to the other module?

For Module 1:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

For Module 2:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <version>version</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```